# Selenium:Not able to read text of a dropdown with autocomplete=off

Tags: jquery, html, css, selenium, autocomplete

Selenium is not able to fetch the text inside the options.

Piece of code which I am writing is:

```
WebElement dropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("selFromAccount"));
List<WebElement> dropoptions=dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for(int i=0;i<dropoptions.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println("Text is "+ dropoptions.get(i).getText());
}   
System.out.println(dropoptions.size());
```

HTML is:

```
<div class=" autocomplete autocomplete-select">
    <select id="selFromAccount" class="ddlsize392 payer-dd loading_input" onchange="changeAjaxAccount(true)" size="1" name="LABEL_NBMAIN_selFromAccount" style="display: none;">
        <option value="-1">Please select a From Account</option>
        <option value="RO56RNCB0318055807340005">Current Account-RO56RNCB0318055807340005-1,49 AUD-false</option>
        <option value="RO59RNCB0187055807340002">Current Account-RO59RNCB0187055807340002-0,53 EUR-false</option>
    </select>
    <input class="input-text search-icon ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" name="LABEL_NBMAIN_selFromAccount_autocomplete" placeholder="Please select a From Account" style="width: 356px; padding-right: 18px;" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"/>
    <a class="show-values" tabindex="-1">
        <span/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Output is:

Text is 
Text is 
Text is 
3

It is taking the count but not able to print the values.

I need to test the value "Please select a From Account" and then need to select the value from the dropdown.Please help.

Comment: Do you want select a spesific item or just print all values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup and ran this myself, getting the same results as you did.  Seems like what is going on is the style="display: none;" is causing getText to return no text as the select is not being displayed.  dropoptions.get(i).getAttribute("text") which works in this case, but the larger issue is that the select is not displayed so cannot be interacted with.  Is this select made visible by some other action on the page?  If not you can make it visible using javascript:

```
WebElement dropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("selFromAccount"));

// Use javascript to display the select, should something on the page trigger displaying of the select?
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String jsHighlight = "document.getElementById(\"selFromAccount\").style.display=\"block\"";
js.executeScript(jsHighlight, dropdown);

List<WebElement> dropoptions=dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for(int i=0;i<dropoptions.size();i++)
{
    // getAttribute("Text") can get the hidden text, but displaying the select is needed to select an option.
    System.out.println(dropoptions.get(i).getAttribute("text"));
    if ("Please select a From Account".equals(dropoptions.get(i).getText())) {
        dropoptions.get(i).click();
    }
}
System.out.println(dropoptions.size());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It works after making it enable using Javascript code.

Comment: @aanchalsuri good to hear! Perhaps you would be so kind as to accept this answer since it resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
WebElement dropdown=driver.findElement(By.id("selFromAccount"));
List<WebElement> dropoptions=dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
java.util.Iterator<WebElement> i = dropoptions.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    WebElement row = i.next();
    System.out.println(row.getText());
}
```